# Cypher query returns duplicated results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph setup:

```
start root=node(0)
create (F {name:'FRAME'}), (I {name: 'INTERACTION'}), (A {name: 'A'}), (B {name: 'B'}),
root-[:ROOT]->F, F-[:FRAME_INTERACTION]->I, I-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]->A, I-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]->B
```

And the following query returns duplicated results:

```
START actor=node:node_auto_index(name='A') 
MATCH actor<-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]-interaction-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]->actor2,
   frame-[:FRAME_INTERACTION]->interaction 
RETURN frame, interaction

Query Results

+-----------------------------------------------------+
| frame                 | interaction                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"FRAME"} | Node[2]{name:"INTERACTION"} |
| Node[1]{name:"FRAME"} | Node[2]{name:"INTERACTION"} |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows
52 ms
```

Even if I add one more start node trying to limit the results, I have the same:

```
START actor=node:node_auto_index(name='A'), frame=node:node_auto_index(name='FRAME') 
MATCH actor<-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]-interaction-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]->actor2,
   frame-[:FRAME_INTERACTION]->interaction 
RETURN frame, interaction
```

I would like to understand why the query returns duplicated results.
I know that it is possible to return unique results by using distinct, but is it possible to change the query in order to return only one result by matching path, without applying an additional operation (distinct)?

(setup and query can be tested at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=q2e0ay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `actor2` to your return list you'll see what the problem is:

```
 frame                 interaction                 actor             actor2
(7 {name:"FRAME"})    (8 {name:"INTERACTION"})    (9 {name:"A"})    (9 {name:"A"})
(7 {name:"FRAME"})    (8 {name:"INTERACTION"})    (9 {name:"A"})    (10 {name:"B"})
```

Actor "A" is being included as a value for actor2! But this makes sense when you think about it, because nowhere in your query did you tell neo4j that `actor` and `actor2` need to be distinct entities.

Luckily it's easy to do:

```
START actor=node:node_auto_index(name='A') 
MATCH actor<-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]-interaction-[:INTERACTION_ACTOR]->actor2,
    frame-[:FRAME_INTERACTION]->interaction 
WHERE actor <> actor2      //like this!
RETURN frame, interaction
```

Comment: Thanks! I was concentrated in a much more complex query, and did not see the solution in front of my eyes in this simple example.